# Infinite loop with socket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, socket.io, infinite

I'm writing my first server card game with react and socket.io. Unfortunately, my server falls into an infinite loop while emit a message to the server and listening to the answer.
Please see the code:
My server:

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
});
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    // agr can be 1 or 2 for different game version
    socket.on("getGamesList", arg => {
        if (arg === "1") {
            socket.emit("sendGamesList1", saboteur1List);
        } else {
            socket.emit("sendGamesList2", saboteur2List);
        }
    });

});

http.listen(4000, () => { console.log("listening on port 4000") });
```

My client site:

1. First I create io instance in App.js file that is responsible for path tracking and pass that socket to all routes to have the same ID through all pages

.

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Games from "./components/Games.jsx";
import GamesList from "./components/GamesList.jsx";
import NewGame from "./components/NewGame.jsx";
import TheGame from "./components/TheGame.jsx";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");

function App() {

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Games />} />
      <Route path="/saboteur/:version" element={<GamesList socket={ socket } />} />
      <Route path="/saboteur/:version/new%20game" element={<NewGame socket={ socket } />} />
      <Route path="/saboteur/:version/game/:gameID" element={<TheGame socket={ socket } />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2. Then I use it to emit a message to the server and listen to the response:

;

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./additionaComponents/Navbar.jsx";
import TableRow from "./additionaComponents/TableRow";


function GamesList(param){
    const saboteurVersion = useParams(); // check the game version to request correct list of games from server
    const [gamesList, setGamesList] = useState();
    const socketListener = "sendGamesList" + saboteurVersion.version;

    useEffect(() => {
        param.socket.on(socketListener, (arg) => {
            setGamesList(
                arg.map((element, indx) => <TableRow {/* keys + values goes here*/} />)
            );
        }); // listen to respond from the server and update gamesList from useState render automaticaly list of games

        param.socket.emit("getGamesList",saboteurVersion.version); // send request to the server for list of games
    });
 
    return( { /* render page components */ } );
}
export default GameList;
```

As effect I receive +50 responses from the server every second.
Would be grateful for any help.
Here you can find full and actual code: https://github.com/ucios-1/saboteur/tree/saboteur-with-server

Comment: did you try to add an empty array as second parameter of the useEffect ?

Comment: VersifiXion, you are my hero!!!! Thank you VERY much! it works. 
By the way, can you share some link where I can read about React logic, so I can understand how it works and why it happened (the infinite loop I mean)

Comment: you have the https://reactjs.org/ official doc, or this website with some resources https://reactresources.com/. The best way is to do some projects by yourself using the most React methods possible

Comment: Thanks! Realy appreciate :)